# How to set default screen options?

Tags: metabox

I'd love to be able to hide meta boxes using screen options, instead of removing them or restricting them to user roles, the goal is to just "uncheck" the meta box for the user.

I see how this would be tricky since any code that would make a DB change for a user wouldn't be allowed to run every time they hit the page because it would just reset. But smarter people than I code the core, so maybe there's a way. And if there is, I'm dying to know.

Any ideas?

Comment: Per username you would have to create your own plugin of sorts that populates all users with a checkbox next to their name and hooks into a filter for showing meta boxes, or multiple meta boxes.

Comment: By _default_ you mean they should be applied once when new user is created, correct?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You are referring to the metaboxes on the admin post screen right?

For that you don't need a plugin, just drop the following into your functions.php file.

```
// add_action('user_register', 'set_user_metaboxes');
add_action('admin_init', 'set_user_metaboxes');
function set_user_metaboxes($user_id=NULL) {

    // These are the metakeys we will need to update
    $meta_key['order'] = 'meta-box-order_post';
    $meta_key['hidden'] = 'metaboxhidden_post';

    // So this can be used without hooking into user_register
    if ( ! $user_id)
        $user_id = get_current_user_id(); 

    // Set the default order if it has not been set yet
    if ( ! get_user_meta( $user_id, $meta_key['order'], true) ) {
        $meta_value = array(
            'side' => 'submitdiv,formatdiv,categorydiv,postimagediv',
            'normal' => 'postexcerpt,tagsdiv-post_tag,postcustom,commentstatusdiv,commentsdiv,trackbacksdiv,slugdiv,authordiv,revisionsdiv',
            'advanced' => '',
        );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, $meta_key['order'], $meta_value );
    }

    // Set the default hiddens if it has not been set yet
    if ( ! get_user_meta( $user_id, $meta_key['hidden'], true) ) {
        $meta_value = array('postcustom','trackbacksdiv','commentstatusdiv','commentsdiv','slugdiv','authordiv','revisionsdiv');
        update_user_meta( $user_id, $meta_key['hidden'], $meta_value );
    }
}
```

Basically what is happening is that for the currently logged in user, you are changing some saved meta_values in the wp_usermeta table.

There are two ways to use this function, you can either hook into 'user_register' or you can hook into 'admin_init'.

The advantage of using 'user_register' is that this function will only fire when a new user is registered (thus lower overhead). However it will not work for users that already exist.

If you want it to work for users that already exist, then hook into 'admin_init'. The disadvantage of course is that now this function fires every time a user goes to the admin page.

Comment: This is **not** a theme job and doesn’t belong into a functions.php.

Comment: @toscho I don't really agree with that. Naturally you could put this into a plugin but if for instance you are building a theme for yourself or perhaps for a client that has no need to see certain boxes then why add the additional management overhead that comes with including this into a plugin. By dropping it into the functions.php file you ensure that the experience for the theme is consistent without having to make sure a plugin is installed and activated.

Comment: There is **no** overhead by using a plugin. That’s a myth which has to die instantly. Plus, your usage restriction was not part of the question. Your answer is read by thousands of novices. You’ll help them with the best code you can write, not with something that kinda works in some specific situations. :)

Comment: +1 Good answer - sometimes you do want to set these explicitly. It's a good base, and of course this code can be modified easily to be called when necessary (adding a new user, for example), so that you really are setting the "default" options and not forcing options on users who change them. I will be adding this code to my theme's `functions.php` file because the default options are for a specific project, which is represented / housed by the theme that I'm developing.

Comment: _Does people want that their shortcodes keep working even if they swap themes?_ The same goes to this kind of function... Even more, I drop the plugin inside `mu-plugins` folder, so it's not easily disabled by the client (this works for WP single installs as well:).

Comment: A couple months after this Answer was written, filters where added to core making this answer obsolete.

Comment: I think @toscho is right in the context of building robust themes and plugins for wide distribution. However, it's important to consider that in addition to thousands of novices trying to hack at prebuilt themes there are also a lot of developers creating custom themes from scratch for a single client meant to work in a single context. Sometimes in that case you have admin features that are intrinsically tied to the custom theme. Doesn't seem the worst idea to include in the theme code if that's the case.

Answer (score 18):

There is `default_hidden_meta_boxes` filter in [`get_hidden_meta_boxes()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_hidden_meta_boxes) that allows to modify which are not shown as long as user hadn't modified his preferences in screen options.

Answer (score 8):

I have code comments about three solutions already posted, but also a general comment

They present a suboptimal choice: either override the user's Screen Options checkbox choice; or respect it but have your code ignored if the user has ever changed the checkboxes, even for other meta_boxes, or before your code was in WP. Seems the respectful choice is only useful if all your users are new. The best solution would be to set a custom user option to determine if your specific meta_box defaults have been changed by the user, and respect that. No, I haven't written that code! Should be easy... :)

The three solutions posted:

**1.** WraithKenny's `hidden_meta_boxes` solution is the one that overrides the user_option. Note it covers all post types ('post', 'page', 'link', 'attachment', and any custom post types). That's fine unless you want it to be specific. You specified the post_type's in your `add_meta_box()` calls. You can try to match those, or just wing it since the ones that don't match will be ignored. If you want to know the post_type in the filter, you can use the extra `screen` parameter:

```
add_filter('hidden_meta_boxes', 'foo_hidden_meta_boxes', 10, 2);
function foo_hidden_meta_boxes($hidden, $screen) {
    $post_type= $screen->id;
    switch ($post_type) {
        // case 'post', 'page', 'link', 'attachment', and any custom post types
        // $hidden[]= 'foo_box_id';
        // /or/
        // $hidden= array_diff($hidden, array('foo_box_id'));
    }
    return $hidden;
}
```

**2.** As Rarst says, `default_hidden_meta_boxes` respects the user_option. As with `hidden_meta_boxes`, you can use the $screen parameter to distinguish post_types.

**3.** Drebabels's set_user_metaboxes() function also respects the user_option. Note it is hard-coded for the 'post' edit screen. To handle the 'page' edit screen, and other post_types, wrap the code in this loop:

```
function set_user_metaboxes($user_id=NULL) {
    $post_types= array( 'post', 'page', 'link', 'attachment' );
    // add any custom post types here:
    // $post_types[]= 'my_custom_post_type';
    foreach ($post_types as $post_type) {

       // These are the metakeys we will need to update
       $meta_key= array(
           'order' => "meta-box-order_$post_type",
           'hidden' => "metaboxhidden_$post_type",
       );

       // The rest is the same as drebabels's code,
       // with '*_user_meta()' changed to '*_user_option()'

       // So this can be used without hooking into user_register
       if ( ! $user_id)
           $user_id = get_current_user_id(); 

       // Set the default order if it has not been set yet
       if ( ! get_user_option( $meta_key['order'], $user_id ) ) {
           $meta_value = array(
               'side' => 'submitdiv,formatdiv,categorydiv,postimagediv',
               'normal' => 'postexcerpt,tagsdiv-post_tag,postcustom,commentstatusdiv,commentsdiv,trackbacksdiv,slugdiv,authordiv,revisionsdiv',
               'advanced' => '',
           );
           update_user_option( $user_id, $meta_key['order'], $meta_value, true );
       }

       // Set the default hiddens if it has not been set yet
       if ( ! get_user_option( $meta_key['hidden'], $user_id ) ) {
           $meta_value = array('postcustom','trackbacksdiv','commentstatusdiv','commentsdiv','slugdiv','authordiv','revisionsdiv');
           update_user_option( $user_id, $meta_key['hidden'], $meta_value, true );
       }
    }
 }
```

Yeah, `get_user_meta` should be `get_user_option`. For single-site it doesn't matter, and even for multi-site it probably doesn't. See wp-admin/includes/ajax-actions.php for why: `update_user_option` has the 'true' global parameter.

Answer (score 2):

```
add_filter( 'hidden_meta_boxes', 'custom_hidden_meta_boxes' );
function custom_hidden_meta_boxes( $hidden ) {
    $hidden[] = 'your_metabox';
    return $hidden;
}
```

There is also `hidden_meta_boxes` filter that would "uncheck" the metabox (making it hidden) on every page load (but wouldn't have to update the database at all). If you just want it off for **new** users until they check the box themselves, use Rarst's answer.